How to estimate 24h RedHat server logs?
I am trying to understand how systemd-journald and rsyslog work together. Are logs are stored in /var/logs? Does
du -h /var/log/journal/

suffice for what I need?

Systemd stores logs in /var/log/journal (assuming it is configured to store logs persistently). Rsyslog stores logs where it has been configured to do so via /etc/rsyslog.conf, typically in /var/log.
On a system running both systemd-journald and rsyslog, journald is generally what actually receives log messages (i.e, by receiving stdout/stderr from systemd-managed services and by listening on /dev/log), and then rsyslog reads them from journald (using the imjournal module).
If you're not doing anything fancy with logs (filtering, splitting into multiple files, sending them to a remote collector, etc), you can remove rsyslog.
